# Pass value from hashtable to a Azure DevOps YAML scheduled task

Tags: foreach, azure-devops, yaml, hashtable, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a scheduled yaml pipeline. 2 Tasks to execute.1st task is to create a hashtable which is combination of subscription and array of resourcegroups. 2nd Task is to call another template using one subscription and one rg from 1st task. Code is mentioned below.

```
steps:

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      $Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
      $AKSSubscriptionAndRG = @{}
 
      foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
      Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $Subscription
      $AKSResourceGroup = (Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters").ResourceGroupName
      if(![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($AKSResourceGroup)){
      $AKSSubscriptionAndRG.add($Subscription.Name,$AKSResourceGroup)
      }
      }
      Write-Output "Exporting pipeline variable AKSSubscription with value AKSRG"
      Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AKSSubscriptionAndRG;]$AKSSubscriptionAndRG"
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    FailOnStandardError: true

- template: another.yaml
  parameters:
    AzureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    AksResourceGroupName: '$(AksResourceGroupName)'
```

My question is : How to pass each subscription and RG to the 2nd template?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, when I pass the `Defined variables` to `AzureSubscription` parameters in template, it seems that the parameters could only recognize the text itself. The defined variable couldn't be passed to the parameters.

Here is the error message:

[image]

This is a known issue. You have to pass the Azure subscription as a literal.

For example:

```
- template: another.yml
  parameters:
     AzureSubscription: Subscriptionname
     AksResourceGroupName: groupname
```

As far as I know, there is no workaround for this now.

Here is a   [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1307)  about this limitation in Github.